# OracleSQL - Pull value from another row without performance impact

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, report

I have a table (table_1) with following columns.

| CURRENCY | COMPANY | ACCOUNT_NUMBER | COST_CENTER | PRODUCT | PART | PROJECT_TEAM | NonUSD_Amt | USD_Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 11 | 2222 | 3333 | 4444 | 5555 | 66666 | 1234 |  |
| GBP | 11 | 2222 | 3333 | 4444 | 5555 | 66666 | 567 |  |

I want both `NonUSD_Amt` and `USD_Amt` values displayed in non-USD row when the values match for rest of the columns. Here is the desired output:

| CURRENCY | COMPANY | ACCOUNT_NUMBER | COST_CENTER | PRODUCT | PART | PROJECT_TEAM | NonUSD_Amt | USD_Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GBP | 11 | 2222 | 3333 | 4444 | 5555 | 66666 | 1234 | 567 |

I am able to achieve this using following query:

```sql
SELECT COMPANY,
       ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       COST_CENTER,
       PRODUCT,
       PART,
       PROJECT_TEAM,
       NonUSD_Amt,
       (SELECT USD_Amt
        FROM   table_1
        WHERE  company = a.company
        AND    account_number = a.account_number
        AND    cost_center = a.cost_center
        AND    product = a.product
        AND    part = a.part
        AND    project_team = a.project_team)
FROM   table_1 a;
```

But this is terribly slowing down the query (especially output export to excel) when the output has 50K plus records. Especially export to excel from Toad is not even completing after hours!!
Are there any alternate ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: How about providing a test CASE with sample data 10k rows or so and posting an explain plan from your query

Comment: Once you have fixed the SQL statement execute performance, then tune the fetching of data over the network from the database.  Many tools have settings to increase the batch size which helps.  E.g. SQL*Plus has `SET ARRAYSIZE`.  Python cx_Oracle has `cursor.arraysize` etc etc.  Bumping these values can help when dealing with large datasets.

Comment: Why are there two rows at all? Why don't you store both attributes in the same row? Then you don't need a query to "repair" this.

Comment: Thank you all! I had forgotten to mention that there is one more column (currency), for which the values wont match. I want the USD value on the non-USD currency row. I have updated my question. Thank you and sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: I doubt that `dual`table has all these columns and suspect you use your table name in both subqueries (though there's no any filter on currency code to select only USD amount). Use `left join` with filter on currency code and then select amount from joined table. This will use hash join which is generally much faster than per row lookup

Comment: hi astentx. Thank you for your response. I meant to have table_1 in the query instead of dual. I have fixed it. I will try the join approach suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COMPANY,
       ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       COST_CENTER,
       PRODUCT,
       PART,
       PROJECT_TEAM,
       sum(NonUSD_Amt) as NonUSD_Amt,
       sum(   USD_Amt) as    USD_Amt
FROM   TABLE_1
GROUP  BY COMPANY,
          ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
          COST_CENTER,
          PRODUCT,
          PART,
          PROJECT_TEAM
;
```